# How does Linux top command determine the state of a Java process?

Tags: java, linux, process, jvm, infinite-loop

[Update: in `top`, after I pressed shift+H, which shows threads rather than processes, it then shows the Java thread as R and using 100% CPU time, which is what I expected before posting this question.]

**Since a Java process has multiple threads, each of which might be in a different state, then how does Linux `top` command determine the Java process state?**

If I run the following code,

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
     while (true){
       int n = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
     }
  }
}
```

Then, running `top` shows that the process state is S, and it's using 100% CPU time.

Also, running `strace` shows and only shows:

`futex(0x7f6ba759c9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 26060, NULL`

However, running `jstack` shows that the main thread is RUNNABLE:

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007fd7ec007800 nid=0x669b runnable [0x00007fd7f5754000]
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at Test.main(Test.java:5)
```

`jstack` also shows that, there are only two threads in WAITING state:

```
"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fd7ec080000 nid=0x66a6 in Object.wait() [0x00007fd7f0252000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000007ad001310> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:133)
        - locked <0x00000007ad001310> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:149)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:177)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fd7ec07e000 nid=0x66a5 in Object.wait() [0x00007fd7f0353000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000007ad0011e8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
        - locked <0x00000007ad0011e8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
```

Comment: The top command aggregates information by process (pid). You can see how many threads total for a process by scoping the command with `-o th`. The usage statistics are aggregated from the active thread for the process.

Answer (score 2):

A JVM has *many* threads running to do "housekeeping" like garbage collection, etc. Those are in sleep state most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

> Then, running top shows that the process state is S, and it's using 100% CPU time.

I think that the issue is most likely with the way that `top` is determining the process status.  At the OS level, it is individual threads that have a run/wait/sleep state.  My guess is that the `top` command's heuristic for figuring out a notional run/wait/sleep state for the process is misleading.

(And the output from `jstack` ... and common sense ... support this theory.)

Comment: The answer can be found in the source code of the top command ... if you are interested enough to find it :-)

Answer (score 0):

This thread is busily using a CPU, it is not sleeping.

```
"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007fd7ec007800 nid=0x669b runnable [0x00007fd7f5754000]
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at Test.main(Test.java:5)
```

This suggests the information in top is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

There's been a lot of explanation of "why you have multiple threads, and what they do in Java", but not that much on what. The `top` command itself is fairly simple, in that it just goes through the system calls necessary to gather information - for example `getrusage` is used to fetch the CPU usage.

Typically, as explained, `top` looks at a whole process, all threads at once. You can press "H" in `top` and it will show individual threads instead of whole process, and you would then be able to see all your Java threads [if your screen is high enough], where the main one is using all the CPU in your infinite loop, and the other threads are mainly doing nothing.